# How to insert the JS variable to DB on click on object in Rails with AJAX?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

How can I update my DB table record on click on image?

```
$('.select_cover img').on('click', function(){
    var src = $(this).attr('src');
});
```

So, I want to insert this SRC variable to database with AJAX? How can I do it?

**P.S** Sorry, I cannot understand AJAX in Rails. Thats why I ask about it. Anyone, please explain me detailed, how can I do it? Model, controller(action), how it must looks? Thank a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You will need to specify a route in your Rails router and create a controller to handle the database insert.

Using this route, you can send an AJAX request like so:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "/route",
  data: { parameter: src }
})
```

You can then retrieve the src variable in your Rails controller like so:

```
params[:parameter]
```

For more information see [Action Controller Overview](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html),
[Rails Routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) and [Active Record Basics (Models)](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html)

Comment: If you already created a Model, you can call Model.create(parameter: params[:parameter]), see the Active Record Basics link above